# Unit Conversion Library - Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Does anyone know of a good unit conversion library that works with Objective-C?  Part of a small app that I'm working on requires me to take two items that are for sale and compare their prices.  This means that I'll have to convert the quantities to a base unit for a valid comparison.

For example, if I have one item that can be purchased for $1 per pint and another that costs $3 per gallon, I need to be able to convert these to a common base unit.

Rather than re-invent the wheel, is there a library out there that can do the base-unit conversion for me?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you ever seen such a thing for any language? I can't even figure how I'd write such a library in a generally reusable way, except to have a file that is just a list of constants.

Comment: @benzado: This kind of stuff already exists: HP28S calculator has this feature for almost all known physical units, combination of units (e.g., "m/s") plus all multiplication factors ("kHz", "mm"). You even can define your own units. As simple as: `1 "$/pt" "$/gal" CONVERT`

Comment: when in doubt convert to moles

Comment: @mouviciel: That's a calculator, not a programming library.

Comment: @benzado C++ has a number of unit conversion libraries. ie. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_units.html and they enforce correct usage at compile time. Very awsome. You will not find something like this in objective C but if you want to use objective C++ you can play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main purpose of a programming library is to abstract away general purpose, reusable code, into a higher level unit where you won't have to care about the details. But this is an area where details probably matter to your project.

Doing math for unit conversions involves a lot of trade-offs between accuracy and performance. If you use native floating point types, you need to avoid situations where a Very Large Number is added to a very small number: the small number may completely vanish. If you use a custom numerical representation, math will be an order of magnitude slower, which may or may not be a problem depending on how much math your application is doing.

Also, choosing that "common base unit" for comparisons is 1,000 times easier if you know what context you are working in. Given your example, it seems like pints or ounces or gallons or even liters might make sense. But if you were working with megaliters, a library that converted everything down to liters might lose a lot of precision. The library would either need to choose a default and be less generic, or allow changing the common unit, which would make it much more complicated (and therefore bug prone).

So, while I can't authoritatively answer your question and say no such library exists, that's why I think you haven't found one.

Answer (score 4):

I've just pushed my Objective-C unit conversion library to GitHub: https://github.com/HiveHicks/HHUnitConverter. Take a look at HHUnitConverter-MacOSX-Example for examples on how to use it.

Comment: Awesome. What you need to do is add a few common default conversions. You could also make it parse/recognize SI prefixes and units, so that `[[HHUnitConverted new] convertString:@"1500 m" toUnit:@"mi"]` would work out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a small number of conversions, you are best rolling your own. Instead of converting to base unit and back, you could have the direct conversion factors (pints->gallons, instead of pints->liters->gallons)

If you can bridge to python, there are many libraries available. [Unum](http://home.scarlet.be/be052320/Unum.html) and [PhysicalQuantities](http://dirac.cnrs-orleans.fr/ScientificPython/ScientificPythonManual/Scientific.Physics.PhysicalQuantities-module.html) are two.

You could also have google do the work if you have internet connectivity, although there is probably a max limit on queries.

Comment: Python and Google are not really practical on iOS, unfortunately.

Comment: Well Apple did get rid of the "section 3.3.1" part of the developers agreement, so it is possible. I think the lack of a good library is because more recent languages (java/python) have better support for very large/precise numbers out of the box. http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/11/21/calling-python-from-objective-c/

Comment: Right: possible, but not practical. Both would be extremely resource intensive for a mobile device, plus Google would require a network connection, given that all you are doing is a table lookup and a multiplication. Cocoa has NSDecimalNumber, if you want big/superprecise numbers.

Comment: Nevertheless, there's an iOS build of Python.

Answer (score 2):

[MKUnits](https://github.com/michalkonturek/MKUnits) is what you look for. This library is very popular among iOS developers. It is available on [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/?q=MKUnits).

It provides units of measurement of physical quantities and simplifies manipulation of them. Unit conversion is very precise and straightforward process. You can easily extend it by adding your own units in no time.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an Objective-c units of measure library called [UnitsKit](https://github.com/stevemoser/UnitsKit). It does more than your basic conversion, for example it handles multiplication of units. Check it out.